# Alias en Linq en el Select new

Tags: c#, gridview, linq-to-sql

```
 var query1 = from ra in contexto.RADICACIONES
                 join us in contexto.USUARIOS on ra.ID_USUARIOS_FK equals us.ID_USUARIOS
                 join usex in contexto.USUARIO_EXTERNO on ra.ID_USUARIO_EXT_FK equals usex.ID_USUARIO_EXT
                 orderby ra.ID_RADICACION descending
                 select new {ra.ID_RADICACION, ra.ASUNTO, ra.FECHA, us.NOMBRE, usex.NOMBRE1 };
    gvradica.DataSource = query1.ToList();
    gvradica.DataBind();
```

Tengo este còdigo y deseo colocar alias en los nombres lo he intentado de las siguiente formas

```
 select new {Id = ra.ID_RADICACION, Asunto = ra.ASUNTO, Fecha = ra.FECHA, Enviado por = us.NOMBRE, Dirigido a = usex.NOMBRE1 };
```

Y también lo he intentado asì

```
 select new {["Id"] = ra.ID_RADICACION,["Asunto"] = ra.ASUNTO,["Fecha"] = ra.FECHA, ["Enviado por:"]  = us.NOMBRE, ["Dirigido a:"] = usex.NOMBRE1 };
```

Y arroja el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los campos son generados automáticamente y pasados a un GridView, deben ser de esta forma, ya que se aplica allí una parte importante de la lógica de negocio, así que no puedo quitar el check de campos autogenerados

Comment: El error dice que no existe `ID_RADICACION`. Revisa tu consulta, en el caso de que necesites alias, solo usa caracteres alfanuméricos `a-z-0-9` y en lugar de espacios, usa guión bajo `_`.

Comment: La consulta funciona, solo que cuando intento colocar el alias aparece el error antes mencionado, intente colocarlo como indicas pero persiste la falla

Answer (score 1):

Lo que veo yo de acuerdo al error que estas presentando, es que puedes tener problemas con los datos nulos que te está devolviendo la consulta (sobretodo el campo FECHA que es el que muestra problema).

Así que deberías intentar de la siguiente forma:

```
select new {Id = (ra.ID_RADICACION ?? 0), Asunto = (ra.ASUNTO ?? ""), Fecha = (ra.FECHA ?? DateTime.MinValue), Enviado por = (us.NOMBRE ?? ""), Dirigido a = (usex.NOMBRE1 ?? "") };
```

**EDICIÓN:**

De acuerdo a tu comentario, entonces ya parece que tuvieras problemas con las propiedades configuradas en el `GridView`, En alguna propiedad del `GridView` tienes establecido el valor *ID_RADICACION* (o esa funcionalidad de la lógica de negocio que comentas en tú pregunta, esta estableciendo este valor) , que al cambiarle el nombre obviamente ya no existe. Revisa bien esto porque el error comienza con la palabra DataBinding que es el evento que se lanza cuando el GridView está tratando de establecer los datos dentro del control.

Recuerda que Linq carga los datos de modo `Lazy`, esto significa que la consulta solo es ejecutada hasta el momento que realmente se necesite. Esto nos va a servir para descartar donde radica el problema, si es la consulta de `LINQ` o si es el `GridView`.

**Actualiza tú código de la siguiente forma:**

```
var query1 = from ra in contexto.RADICACIONES
             join us in contexto.USUARIOS on ra.ID_USUARIOS_FK equals us.ID_USUARIOS
             join usex in contexto.USUARIO_EXTERNO on ra.ID_USUARIO_EXT_FK equals usex.ID_USUARIO_EXT
             orderby ra.ID_RADICACION descending
             select new {Id = ra.ID_RADICACION, Asunto = ra.ASUNTO, Fecha = ra.FECHA, Enviado por = us.NOMBRE, Dirigido a = usex.NOMBRE1 };

var pruebas = query1.ToList();
gvradica.DataSource = pruebas;
gvradica.DataBind();
```

Si tú ejecución pasa la línea `var pruebas = query1.ToList();` significa que el problema es el `GridView`, sin tú ejecución no pasa esta línea entonces el problema es la consulta `LINQ`.

Comment: Persiste el error, la consulta trae resultados sin problemas en todos los campos

Comment: @Ledferoz10 ok. Ya edite la respuesta para que le des un vistazo.

Comment: Solventado, era un tema en una propiedad del GridView

Comment: @Ledferoz10 Que bien!!! me alegra que hayas resuelto tu inconveniente.

Comment: @Ledferoz10 Si ya solucionaste tu problema, quizá sería lo ideal que lo publicaras como respuesta por si a alguien le puede servir en el futuro

Answer (score 0):

Podrías solucionar tu problema con la palabra *let* dentro de tu consulta. Esto crea una variable donde puedes almacenar resultados.

```
List<string> lista = new List<string> { "uno", "dos", "tres"};
var collection = from x in lista let num1 = x[0] where num1.Equals("uno") select new { x, num1 };
```